# Redirect http://wildcard.dev.example.nl to https://wildcard.dev.example.nl in Application Gateway

Tags: azure, redirect, gateway, azureportal

We have an application gateway and I have al list of dns we control. The list:

1. seq.dev.example.nl
2. dashboard.dev.example.nl
3. login.dev.example.nl

All the others where we have no control over we to redirect to the https version so -> http://test.dev.example.nl we want to redirect to https://test.dev.example.nl

My listener:
[image: This is the listener]
My Rule:
[image: this is my rule]

When i want to try and save it I got the follow error:

[image]

Does anyone knows a work around or something?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting some limitations here

You can't use a wildcard or multiple host names in a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview) rule with a target listener. As a result, you cannot build an HTTP to HTTPS redirect while using wild card listeners.

Reference 1 : [Considerations and limitations of using wildcard or multiple host names in a listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview#considerations-and-limitations-of-using-wildcard-or-multiple-host-names-in-a-listener)

Reference 2: [Deploying a Wildcard Azure Application Gateway using Powershell](https://medium.com/wortell/deploying-a-wildcard-azure-application-gateway-using-powershell-51960ecbf051)